# Implementation of C Standard Library Function ntohl()

Tags: c, reinventing-the-wheel, integer, library, bitwise

This is an implementation of `ntohl()` that I wrote as an exercise. `ntohl()` takes a `uint32_t` value and returns it unchanged if the host architecture is network-byte-order (big-endian), otherwise the value is converted to host-byte-order.

My version converts to little-endian; is it always the case that host-byte-order is taken to mean little-endian? This appears to be the case, from what I have read, but what if the host architecture is middle-endian? Do real implementations of `ntohl()` detect other byte-orders, or strictly big- and little-endian?

I am also interested in any comments about the use of a `union` to detect endianness on the host machine, suggestions and comparison with other methods, and similarly, comments and suggestions relating to the use of bitwise operators to perform the conversion from big-endian to little-endian.

```
#ifndef _STDINT_H
#include <stdint.h>
#endif

uint32_t my_ntohl(uint32_t netlong)
{
    union {
        uint16_t num;
        uint8_t bytes[2];
    } endian_test = { .bytes = { 0x01, 0x00 }};

    if (endian_test.num == 0x0001) {
        netlong = (netlong << 24) | ((netlong & 0xFF00ul) << 8) |
            ((netlong & 0xFF0000ul) >> 8) | (netlong >> 24);
    }

    return netlong;
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unless you wish to optimize the code, with specialized swappers for various hosts orders, you are doing it wrong.

I invite you to check [The Byte Order Fallacy](https://commandcenter.blogspot.nl/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html) by Rob Pike. The punch line: the byte order of the computer you are executing the code on doesn't matter, because the language abstracts it for you.

Thus, only the byte order of the network matters, and the network is big-endian:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

uint32_t ntohl(uint32_t const net) {
    uint8_t data[4] = {};
    memcpy(&data, &net, sizeof(data));

    return ((uint32_t) data[3] << 0)
         | ((uint32_t) data[2] << 8)
         | ((uint32_t) data[1] << 16)
         | ((uint32_t) data[0] << 24);
}
```

This function will work no matter the endianness of the host, even on the crazy middle-endians ones.

Oh, and it optimizes well in general, in case you were wondering:

> ```
> ntohl(unsigned int):
>         mov     eax, edi
>         bswap   eax
>         ret
> ```

`bswap` being the native CPU instruction to swap bytes on x86.

Comment: I'm wondering what a typical compiler emits for a big endian machine.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: hopefully, it just mov the argument into the return slot.

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly, this is a clever use of the fact that bitshift operations work on the value, not the underlying representation. But I have one question. It seems that this relies on the integer promotions to convert `data[i]` to `unsigned int`. Shouldn't there be a cast here, e.g., `((uint32_t) data[3] << 0)`, so that a `uint32_t` value is returned? Also, thanks for the link to Pike's essay.

Comment: Also, do the empty braces in `uint8_t data[4] = { }` zero-initialize the array `data`? This gives me a warning with `-Wpedantic`, but the code still works. Does this array even need to be initialized, given that 32 bits are immediately copied into it?

Comment: @DavidBowling: Yes, you understand it correctly. As for the cast, it is necessary for portability; this short form relies on the fact that `int` is at least 4 bytes because all smaller integers are promoted to `int` before any arithmetic operation occurs. And since it's `int`, there might be an issue of shifting into the sign bit.

Comment: @DavidBowling: It need not be initialized, I just do it out of habit since reading unassigned values is undefined behavior. Works pretty well in C++, but in C you might need `= { 0 };`.

Comment: Thanks. This was a great answer. The empty braces worked for me, but I just wanted to look at the warning, and I haven't seen the empty-brace initializer before. I thought that smaller `unsigned` integers were promoted to `unsigned int`-- is that wrong?

Comment: @DavidBowling: Unfortunately no. It's `int` if it can represent all values of the type, and `unsigned int` only the value doesn't fit in an `int`. And anything that has less bits than an `int` will fit in an `int`. (see http://www.idryman.org/blog/2012/11/21/integer-promotion/)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `memcpy(data, &net, sizeof(data));`?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: Same same. Either you explicitly turn `data` into a pointer like I did, or you rely on the fact that arrays decay into pointer like you did. I prefer explicit, in general, thus `&data`.

Comment: I just wanted to mention that `ntohl` and `htonl` can use the exact same implementation presented here. So you can alias one to the other :)

Answer (score 7):

To properly check the byte order, you must check it using `uint32_t`, since on [the PDP-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Middle-endian) the value 0x01020304 was stored as `02 01 04 03`, appropriately called middle-endian. There are 21 other possibilites to arrange the bytes.

You don't need the `ul` suffix since the operands of binary operators are subject to *the usual arithmetic conversions*. Furthermore, it is considered bad style to use a lowercase ell as a suffix since it can be confused with a 1.

Don't use an inclusion guard around the `#include`. Just include the header. As it is now, your code depends on the internals of the `<stdint.h>` header, which it shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I am still getting used to inclusion guards, and I guess I did not really need one here. I think that the only place I ever use lowercase ells in identifiers is with hexadecimal literals, and this is to set the suffix off from the digits. But it always makes me wince a little, and this is a style point that I have not settled for myself yet.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I only check for little-endian byte order, which is why I used `uint16_t`. Does the library version of `ntohl()` check for PDP-endianness? What about other middle-endian schemes?

Comment: @DavidBowling The `ntohl` which comes with your compiler is most likely a compiler built-in or comes with the system library for the specific target CPU designed to squeeze out the last bit of performance, i.e. it will not be a function, and it will not be portable, and it will not be C. Some drivers may rely on that performance.  It will specifically be not even a NOP for big endian machines. If you strive for portable code, however, @Matthieu has said it all in his answer.

Answer (score 4):

### Consider exploiting the compiler

Your compiler already needs to know the endianness of the target system.  There's a good chance that it exposes that information in a way you can access.  `gcc` for example defines macros, so you can do:

```
#if ((__BYTE_ORDER__) == (__ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__))
```

and have different code blocks as appropriate.

### Don't repeat yourself

Your current approach declares `endian_test` as a local variable.  Depending on how clever your compiler is, it may optimize some of the work out for you. However you should consider giving it hints by declaring the variable as a `static` (you don't need a new instance for every call) `const` (you don't need to modify it after its declaration).

Comment: I was aware that such macros exist, but I have not really looked into them yet since they seem to be implementation-dependent. Thanks for the `static const` tip. I should have thought of this. In my original code I did not use the designated initializer, so `const` was not an option, and I missed this when I changed it. But missing `static` was just a silly oversight!

Comment: Good tip about macros. You generally will check if well-known implementations(clang, gcc, vscc) define such macros to find the BO; if not, simply fall back to runtime checks.